# Find out which pages I will be on Mobile

Tags: php, javascript, css

thinking right moment to for building my page on the mobile user willing, it should be such that they came to the site so it must be a box up asking the user whether to be on the right side or on the mobile site, it must only do if you are on a mobile phone, however in fashion if one is on his computer has been unable to do so.

If you think that you must be on the mobile page so you will be kicked over to m.mobil.com

if you want to stay on the normal side are you just mobil.com,

It will only do it if it's android, iphone or window phone

It will not do it if you are his ipad or similar mobiles such as ipad.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using PHP I recommend the Mobile_Detect Class. I works well for me and easy.

https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

It detects just about any mobile device. This could be in your `index.php` file

Example usage.

```
 <?php
        // Include and instantiate the class.
        require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
        $detect = new Mobile_Detect;

        // Any mobile device (phones or tablets).
        if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
        //do stuff, redirect or whatever
        }

        // Check if an iphone, ipad etc:
        if( $detect->isiOS() ){
        //do stuff, redirect or whatever
        }
        //check if an Android device
        if( $detect->isAndroidOS() ){
        //do stuff, redirect or whatever
        }

 ?>
```